# Docker: Selenium Hub and a Chrome Node errors with [SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

Our NightwatchJs tests started to fail with the error

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}) on port 13969
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1561022833.301][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

We are using docker to setup a Selenium hub/grid with a Chrome node. Any idea on how to downgrade to ChromeDriver version 74?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the version temporarily while it gets sorted out by selecting a specific image for the chrome node:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444"
  chrome-node:
    # Fix Chrome version to 74, as 75 errors with [SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-oxygen
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5555"
```